# Case or decode on multiple rows

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I have to achieve the result in HIVE from the input table with the given condition as shared in image. Is this possible to get that in a single query with some functions without adding any additional column?[image]

Queries to create temp table :-

```
 Create table test(`serial_no` string,`location` string, `status` string,`row_num` int);
     INSERT INTO test values('ABC','CA','S',1);
     INSERT INTO test values('ABC','CA','P',2);
     INSERT INTO test values('ABC','CA','F',3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use min() or max() aggregation with case statement:

```
 select serial_no, location, 
        max(case when (row_num=1 and status='S') OR ( row_num=2 and status='P') then 'Passed' end) result 
   from test 
  group by serial_no, location;
```

Result:

```
OK
serial_no       location        result
ABC             CA              Passed
Time taken: 61.036 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select distinct a.serial_no, a.location, case when S = P then 'passed' end result
   from(
        select serial_no, location,
        case when row_num = 1 and status = 'S' then 1 else 0 end S
        from test) a
   inner join (
        select serial_no, location,
        case when row_num = 2 and status = 'P' then 1 else 0 end P
        from test) b 
   on a.serial_no = b.serial_no and b.location = b.location and p <> 0 and s <> 0
 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below using collect_list function and then apply group by. I have not validated the performance and you can look at the mapper used in this case.

```
select  serial_no,  uslocation , 
case when 
collect_list(condition_1)[0] = 1 and 
collect_list(condition_2)[0] = 'S' and 
collect_list(condition_3)[0] = 2 and 
collect_list(condition_4)[0] = 'P'
then 'Passed' else 'Failed' end result_field
from 
(
select
serial_no,
uslocation,
CASE WHEN row_num=1 THEN row_num END AS condition_1,
CASE WHEN status='S' THEN status END AS condition_2,
CASE WHEN row_num=2 THEN row_num END AS condition_3,
CASE WHEN status='P' THEN status END AS condition_4
from 
test_tbl
) dummy_tble
group by serial_no, uslocation
```

[image: Result before applying case statement]

[image: Result from cloudera hive console]